# Undefined object

Tags: javascript, react-native, for-loop

I have this simple set of data in an array like so:

```
const mockData = 
{ "data" :
  [
    {
      "id": "76",
      "name": "Dude",
      "time": "08:30"
    },
    {
      "id": "77",
      "name": "Hello",
      "time": "08:40"
    },
  ]
}
```

I wanted to access each object using for loop, but returned with undefined instead. When I access directly like `mockData.data[0].name`, I'll get the correct data. But when I use the `for loop`, I'll be returned with `undefined is not an object(evaluating mockData.data[i].name` and breaks my app. I'm not sure exactly what's happening, if anyone cares to explain would be nice. `Here's my for loop` (pretty straight forward).

```
for(let i = 0; i<=mockData.data.length; i++) {
    if(mockData.data[i].name == "Dude") { //this is the part where the object is undefined
          ... do something
    }
}
```

Comment: use i < mockData.data.length so that you do not actually get to mockData.data.length

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your condition inside `for loop` is wrong. It should be like `i < mockData.data.length`

```
for(let i = 0; i < mockData.data.length; i++) {}
```

```js
const mockData = 
{ "data" :
  [
    {
      "id": "76",
      "name": "Dude",
      "time": "08:30"
    },
    {
      "id": "77",
      "name": "Hello",
      "time": "08:40"
    },
  ]
}

for(let i = 0; i< mockData.data.length; i++) {
    if(mockData.data[i].name == "Dude") {
      console.log('hi')
    }
}
```